# How to add border radius for a table cell, not working on all browsers

Tags: html, css

I have created a simple datatable using divs with table css property. But when I try to add rounded borders for my table it is not working in Firefox. It works only in Chrome. Is there another way how to add the rounded border radius like this?

[image]

Here is my table

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.datatable-table {
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 100%;
 
}

.datatable-rows {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 43px;
  background-color: #fff;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.datatable-filters {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 43px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}

.datatable-header {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 43px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  background: #dedede;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.datatable-header .datatable-cell:first-child {
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 0;
}

.datatable-header .datatable-cell:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 3px 0 0;
}

.datatable-rows .datatable-cell:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 6px;
}

.datatable-rows .datatable-cell:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 6px 0;
}

.datatable-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="datatable-table">
    <div class="datatable-filters">
      <div class="datatable-cell">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
          <input type="text" value="2019-05-12" style="width: 47%">
          <input type="text" value="2019-05-12" style="width: 47%">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="datatable-cell">Row 1, Column 2</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Date added</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
    </div>
    <!-- datatable-filters -->

    <div class="datatable-header">
      <div class="datatable-cell">Date added</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Date changed</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short things</div>
    </div>
    <!-- datatable-header -->

    <div class="datatable-rows">
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-01-01</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
    </div>
    <!-- datatable-rows -->
  </div>
  <!-- datatable -->

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Here is a working scratchpad fiddle
http://scratchpad.io/glib-line-6058

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This took me a while to figure out, but apparently, it has to do with the background-color of some of the tags. The border-radius is working perfectly fine, but it doesn't show up because its parent element has the same background-color. Chrome ignores this issue but Firefox doesn't.

What I changed:

1. I removed the backgrounds from the `.datatable-header` and the `.data-table-rows`.
2. I added

```
.datatable-header .datatable-cell {
  background: #dedede; 
}

.datatable-rows .datatable-cell {
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

Live Snippet: (I exaggerated the border-radii so they would show up more easily.)

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  background-color: #efefef;
}

.container {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 50px 50px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.datatable-table {
  display: table;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 100%;
 
}

.datatable-rows {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 43px;
  font-family: Roboto, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5;
  font-size: 14px;
}

.datatable-filters {
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 43px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}

.datatable-header {
  border-radius: 6px 6px 0 0;
  display: table-row;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 43px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #7a7a7a;
  border-radius: 3px 3px 0px 0px;
  padding: 15px 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.datatable-header .datatable-cell {
  background: #dedede; 
}

.datatable-rows .datatable-cell {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.datatable-header .datatable-cell:first-child {
  border-radius: 6px 0 0 0;
}

.datatable-header .datatable-cell:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 6px 0 0;
}

.datatable-rows .datatable-cell:first-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 0 12px;
}

.datatable-rows .datatable-cell:last-child {
  border-radius: 0 0 12px 0;
}

.datatable-cell {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 20px;
  width: 150px;
  margin: 5px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="datatable-table">
    <div class="datatable-filters">
      <div class="datatable-cell">
        <div style="display: flex; justify-content: space-between;">
          <input type="text" value="2019-05-12" style="width: 47%">
          <input type="text" value="2019-05-12" style="width: 47%">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="datatable-cell">Row 1, Column 2</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Date added</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
    </div>
    <!-- datatable-filters -->

    <div class="datatable-header">
      <div class="datatable-cell">Date added</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Date changed</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short thing</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">Some short things</div>
    </div>
    <!-- datatable-header -->

    <div class="datatable-rows">
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-01-01</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
      <div class="datatable-cell">2019-05-12</div>
    </div>
    <!-- datatable-rows -->
  </div>
  <!-- datatable -->

</div>
<!-- container -->
```

Comment: Adding -moz- doesn't solve the problem. It's still not working.

Comment: @Liga You're right. The problem has nothing to do with browser compatibility and I have changed my answer accordingly. Hope this helps!